# Error after update Ubuntu updating from 20.10 to Hirsute Hippo (21.04)

Tags: 21.04

When trying to update, the error weighs:

```
FATAL ERROR:
Both /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 and /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 exist.

You can try correcting the errors reported and running again
/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge until it will complete without errors.
Do not install or update other Debian packages until the program
has been run successfully.

dpkg: error processing usrmerge package (--configure): 
installed usrmerge package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

I tried to fix it with the commands: `sudo apt -f install`, `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, nothing helps, the error does not disappear!
Tell me how you can fix it?

Comment: You may want to report it as a bug. https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/report-ubuntu-bug.html.en

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate what you were updating from to 21.04 and the steps taken to do so.

Comment: Have you tried to run `sudo /usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge` ?

Comment: Tried it, it did not help (, Here is the log from the terminal below:

Comment: FATAL ERROR:
Both /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 and /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 exist.

You can try correcting the errors reported and running again
/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge until it will complete without errors.
Do not install or update other Debian packages until the program
has been run successfully.

Answer (score 13):

Thank you! I found a solution to my problem! Maybe someone will come in handy!

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
sudo rm usrmerge.*
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: I tried, but no success.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you

Comment: Initially seemed to work, but then had problems with docker always referring to `usrmerge`. Reinstalling `docker-ce` does not help

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the problem. It is kinda linked to https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/TheCaseForTheUsrMerge/ (I did not followed all the history of this).

I identified also files were duplicated between /bin and /usr/bin for example, but more recent in /bin. And `usrmerge` was unable to managed this situation. So I helped him and I did this:

```bash
for f in `find /bin -mindepth 1 ! -type l`; do sudo mv $f /usr/bin/$(basename ${f}); sudo ln -s /usr/bin/$(basename ${f}) $f;done
for f in `find /sbin -mindepth 1 ! -type l`; do sudo mv $f /usr/sbin/$(basename ${f}); sudo ln -s /usr/sbin/$(basename ${f}) $f;done
for f in `find /lib/systemd/system -mindepth 1 ! -type l`; do sudo mv $f /usr/lib/systemd/system/$(basename ${f}); sudo ln -s /usr/lib/systemd/system/$(basename ${f}) $f;done
for f in `find /lib/udev/rules.d -mindepth 1 ! -type l`; do sudo mv $f /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/$(basename ${f}); sudo ln -s /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/$(basename ${f}) $f;done
```

It can be adapted to any folder in conflict. For your case, I think:

```bash
for f in `find /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -mindepth 1 ! -type l`; do sudo mv $f /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/$(basename ${f}); sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/$(basename ${f}) $f;done
```

*It only creates symlinks pointing to /usr/*.*

Comment: All those files you are moving around belong to various packages,and I imagine that you will have created a lot of future problems with updating those packages.

Comment: No problem at all since this post neither since 2012, the year of my last fresh install of Linux I have ever done on my native Linux machine. Updated & upgraded every week , regularly moved on different hardware, without any (major) problem. Of course, when you move / modify system binaries, you take some risk. I know them and how to fix them. Users should learn them too.

Answer (score 1):

I had a system where *many* files in different subdirectories of /usr would have to have corrected manually in order to get `/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge` running w/o errors.

Inspired by the answer from @cactuschibre I created a little shell script which does an automated correction of a given directory with some more sanity  checks:

```bash
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                                                                                                           

dir=$1

if [ ! -d $dir -o ! -d /usr/$dir ]; then
    exit 1
fi

verbose () {
    echo "$@" >&2
    "$@"
}

for f in $(find $dir -mindepth 1 ! -type l ! -type d); do

    # check if the same file exists in /usr
    #
    if [ -e /usr$f ]; then

        echo "---" >&2

        # check if either the file in /usr is older or if both files are the same
        #
        if [ /usr$f -ot $f ] || cmp -s /usr$f $f; then

            ls -l $f /usr$f
            dpkg -S $f
            dpkg -S /usr$f

            # if the `dpkg -S /usr$f command above failed it means that no
            # package installed the file to /usr. Therefore it should be safe
            # to overwrite the file in /usr w/o interfering with an installed
            # package.
            #
            if [ $? = 1 ]; then
                verbose rm /usr$f
                verbose mv $f /usr$f
                verbose ln -s /usr$f $f
            fi
        else
            echo /usr$f is newer than $f or files are not the same. >&2
            echo PLEASE RESOLVE THIS CONFLICT MANUALLY. >&2
        fi
    fi
done
```

Use the script like this:

1. start with `/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge`
2. if `convert-usrmerge` returns with an error with a file in a certain directory (e.g. /lib) then call the above script with this directory
3. the script will correct all files in the given directory
4. start over with 1. `convert-usrmerge` will possibly complain about a conflict in another directory...

Comment: I'm thinking I needs something similar, but in my case the bad duplicate files are not owned by any packages, which can be checked with e.g. `dpkg-query -S /usr/bin/bash`.  As a more cautious first step I want to only delete files in `/usr/bin` that are not owned by any package, and where there's a duplicate in `/bin`.  thanks for writing most of the script I want though.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

complains that:
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'usrmerge' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed

but it runs fine otherwise, so I can live with this.