# FATAL ERROR: Both /lib/udev/hwdb.bin and /usr/lib/udev/hwdb.bin exist

Tags: upgrade, udev, 21.04

After upgrading from Ubuntu 20.10 to 21.04, I get the following error:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up usrmerge (24ubuntu3) ...

FATAL ERROR:
Both /lib/udev/hwdb.bin and /usr/lib/udev/hwdb.bin exist.

You can try correcting the errors reported and running again
/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge until it will complete without errors.
Do not install or update other Debian packages until the program
has been run successfully.

dpkg: error processing package usrmerge (--configure):
 installed usrmerge package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 usrmerge
```

I searched for posts and articles about this specific error but I can't find anything.
Any ideas to solve it ?

Comment: See which package the files belong to with `dpkg -S /lib/udev/hwdb.bin; dpkg -S /usr/lib/udev/hwdb.bin`

Comment: Of course they both exist, they are the same file since  /lib and /usr/lib became the same directory.  Seems like a package error.

Comment: @waltinator they don't belong to any package:
`$ dpkg -S /lib/udev/hwdb.bin`

`dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /lib/udev/hwdb.bin`

`$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/udev/hwdb.bin`
`dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/lib/udev/hwdb.bin`

Comment: @ubfan1 yes it looks like some error from the scripts which are supposed to merged these directories. I found another question that may be related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333784/error-after-update-ubuntu-updating-from-20-10-to-hirsute-hippo-21-04

Comment: Thanks guys, I filled a bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1930573. I'll let you know.

Answer (score 1):

`hwdb.bin` is a generated file. I did check it in Ubuntu 20.04, `/lib/udev/hwdb.bin` and `/usr/lib/udev/hwdb.bin` using `stat` same exact size and confirmed with `vbindiff`. They are identical copy, so no need to be merged.

A quick fix would be deleting one of them:

```
sudo rm /lib/udev/hwdb.bin
```

It is still bug that better get reported. I should look why such generated file is not put in `/var`.

Comment: Thanks @user.dz. I already reported it: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usrmerge/+bug/1930573